# IsInRole returns false for workgroup roles

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication, user-roles

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC4 Razor application and I'd like to use Windows authentication to restrict access to various functions to users who are members of specific Windows groups.  I'm developing on a Windows 8 VM (named MYVM) which is not domain-joined, but the app will be deployed on a Win2008 server which will be domain-joined.

I've configured web.config as follows:

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"/>
```

Authentication works - @User.Identity.Name displays "MYVM\MYUSERNAME"

However, although I've added my account to a couple of Windows Groups, calls to @User.IsInRole("GROUP_NAME") always returns false.

I suspect this is because my development VM is not domain-joined.  Does anyone know if Windows auth in ASP.NET MVC works with workgroup roles as well as domain roles?

EDIT

I've found out that I can enumerate the roles - this gives:

```
?System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser()
{string[9]}
[0]: "None"
[1]: "CONSOLE LOGON"
[2]: "Everyone"
[3]: "NT AUTHORITY\\This Organization"
[4]: "NT AUTHORITY\\INTERACTIVE"
[5]: "NT AUTHORITY\\Authenticated Users"
[6]: "NT AUTHORITY\\NTLM Authentication"
[7]: "LOCAL"
[8]: "BUILTIN\\Users"
```

However, when I look at my group membership in the Manage Computer screen, I'm in the following groups:

```
Administrators
Users
GROUP_NAME
```

So: @User.IsInRole("None") returns true; @User.IsInRole("GROUP_NAME") returns false.

Where is the GetRolesForUser picking up the group list from?

Comment: Not sure I quite understand your answer - IsInRole("MYVM\\GROUP_NAME") returns false; IsInRole("BUILTIN\\Users") returns true.  IsInRole is just checking the list returned by GetRolesForUser.  I'll try Reflector as you suggest.

Comment: Using domain-joined VM's is a nightmare with a frequently-changing password policy (try resuming a VM after a couple of months downtime and having to remember the password from the last time you used the VM!).  So my question is whether AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider can read groups from the local machine, or just from a domain?

Comment: Yes - tried other local groups, but no success.  I've worked round the problem by implementing a SQL role provider instead.  Thanks for your pointers anyway...

Comment: No worries. Sorry I couldn't help more. I'm going to delete most of my comments to avoid clutter.